# Angular 10 display object value as per user input property

Tags: angular, angular10

Consider an **object** `emp` having properties `name` and `age`.

As per the user input in the text box name or age, I need to display the value from the object.

Normally we can display as `{{emp.name}}` or `{{emp.age}}`
but in my case, the property of `emp` is **dynamic**.

> For example: If an input text is x then the emp property should have `x` in it. like `{{emp.x}}`

How to achieve this?

> Property name should be taken from the user input. No condition or logical things.

Same regarding `ngmodel` as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello @user2527732,
would this work
    {{emp[input.value]}} 
or something like it what you are looking for ?
Or maybe an other approach would be to subscribe to the input's change in your component and assign a new variable in there.

Comment: Did you consider bracket notation to access the objects fields? E.g. instead of `emp.name` you could use `emp['name']`. In this case, the key can also be a variable like `emp[someVariable]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to determine the value of a dynamic property, you should be doing it like this:

```
{{ emp['x'] }}
```

Bracket notation looks for properties on the object with the name inside them.

Comment: Yes your thread helped on this.
property:any='age';
{{emp[property]}} will dynamically display it as per the change